# Hiding Query String to show in URL: URL Rewriting

Tags: java, javascript, struts2, url-rewriting, query-string

I am calling one JS function to open a new window by clicking a button

```
function showReport(){
window.open("reports.action?repType=RPDRep&selectedProjects=${projectSelect}");
}
```

projectSelect values I am getting from Action class of the calling page.

It calls another action with these values and generate expected result.

It works fine but the only problem is My values are getting exposed in URL like this

```
http://localhost:9080/xyz/reports.action?repType=RPDRep&selectedProjects=DE-06-00273
```

Kindly let me if there is any method to convert URL into something meaningful without showing input details to users. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this,before sending data convert into post.

```
    function showReport(){
      $.post("reports.action", {repType : "RPDRep" ,selectedProjects :"+ ${projectSelect}+" }, function(data){
        var post_window = window.open();
        $(post_window.document.body).append(data);
      });
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could maybe just change the window location as such:

```
function showReport(){ var w1 =window.open("reports.action?repType=RPDRep&selectedProjects=${projectSelect}"); w1.location.href='http://www.yourLocation.com'; }
```

BR/ Dan

Comment: I do not have any absolute location to mention for the page that will open, Its an dynamic page based on few business logic done on Action Class.
I was searching for something that can hide the query string, such as POST method in case of form action method